# Font letters are outputed as symbols

Tags: php, fonts

Hey guys ive just translated website to my language and it ha ąčęėįšųūž ant etc letters. It is Lithuanian. And ive got problem, when website output report info to pdf file, these letters become `?, &scaron;,` and other symbols. Here is my code, how can i make it undrestand the letters:

```
$font_dir = DP_BASE_DIR.'/lib/ezpdf/fonts';

require($AppUI->getLibraryClass('ezpdf/class.ezpdf'));

$pdf = new Cezpdf($paper='A4',$orientation='landscape');
$pdf->ezSetCmMargins(1, 2, 1.5, 1.5);
$pdf->selectFont("$font_dir/AbrilFatface.afm");

$pdf->ezText(safe_utf8_decode(dPgetConfig('company_name')), 12);

$date = new CDate();
$pdf->ezText("\n" . $date->format($df) , 8);
$last_week = new CDate($date);
$last_week->subtractSpan(new Date_Span(array(7,0,0,0)));

$pdf->selectFont("$font_dir/AbrilFatface.afm");
$pdf->ezText("\n" . safe_utf8_decode($AppUI->_('Project Completed Task Report')), 12);
$pdf->ezText(safe_utf8_decode($pname), 15);
$pdf->ezText(safe_utf8_decode($AppUI->_('Tasks Completed Since')) . " " . $last_week->format($df) , 10);
$pdf->ezText("\n");
$pdf->selectFont("$font_dir/AbrilFatface.afm");
$title = null;
$options = array(
    'showLines' => 2,
    'showHeadings' => 1,
    'fontSize' => 9,
    'rowGap' => 4,
    'colGap' => 5,
    'xPos' => 50,
    'xOrientation' => 'right',
    'width'=>'750',
    'shaded'=> 0,
    'cols'=>array(
        0=>array('justification'=>'left','width'=>250),
        1=>array('justification'=>'left','width'=>95),
        2=>array('justification'=>'center','width'=>75),
        3=>array('justification'=>'center','width'=>75),
        4=>array('justification'=>'center','width'=>75))
);
```

Ive tried changing fonts to `Abril Fatface`. But that ddnt helped, so what can  i do?

Comment: It is always three things you have to take care of: you have to specify the encoding of the strings you write into the document, you have to specify the document encoding and you have to provide a font that actually provides the glyphs you want to get rendered. Note especially that the font has to be either embedded in the document or _it has to be available on the client side_, so on the system of whoever person receives and wants to open your document. As a rule of thumb for the encoding: always and only use clean utf-8 encoding. Do not convert back and forth!